# Where to add files Linux ISO

Tags: linux, boot, iso, debian-installer

I have a Debian 11 ISO file. I used the procedure described here https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD to open, edit, and re-make the bootable iso.
I want to add a bash script that I can use to configure the system after installation. The problem is that I don't know where to put the script.

I tried putting it on pool/main/ and /dists/bullseye/ but, after the installation, the script was gone. I searched for it with the find command.